# How to use gradient color in react-native art shape stroke

Tags: android, ios, svg, react-native

I want to make a gradient color progress bar.
This is my code.

```
const linearGradient = new LinearGradient({
        '0': '#EC6474',
        '1': '#7F5CFA'
     },
      "0", "0", "300", "0"
    );
     <Surface 
      width={this.props.style.width} 
      height={this.props.style.height}>
                    <Group>
                        <Shape
                            d={this.state.backgroundPath}
                            strokeWidth={this.props.backgroundLineHeight}
                            stroke='#aaaaab'
                            strokeCap="square"
                            strokeJoin="miter"/>
                        <Shape
                            d={this.state.abovePath}
                            strokeWidth={this.props.aboveLineHeight}
                            stroke={linearGradient}
                            strokeCap="butt" strokeJoin="bevel"/>
                    </Group>
                </Surface>
```

But it throw an error:

> Cannot read property 'slice' of null

It is not support gradient？

I know svg can do this.

but I still want to use React Native .

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?